# Reduce size of the Xcode application

Tags: macos, xcode, disk-space

Is there anyway to reduce the disk space used to store the Xcode application? I only downloaded Xcode so that I could compile C and C++, so if possible I would like it to take up much less than the 9.22GB it requires right now. Perhaps there are optional portions I can uninstall?

Answer (score 69):

Although it's not directly related to the Xcode app size. There are multiple places where you can delete files to free up some space.

**1. Derived Data**
Xcode keeps data about your projects which includes index, build output and logs. Go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and delete the folders for projects that you no longer need to keep this data around for.

**2. iOS Device Support**
Xcode is storing information about the devices you have used for development. Delete the data no longer needed in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/`.

**3. Archives**
Delete the one’s you don’t need in the Organizer, or go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/` to delete them in bulk. Be careful not to delete archives for which you still need the dSYM data for debugging.

**4. Simulators**
Simulators are stored under `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`. For each version of iOS you are building for.

**5. Documentation** Browse and delete unnecessary data under `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets`.

Comment: I only have 3 folders in `Xcode`: `DerivedData`,`iOS Device Logs`, and `UserData`. The first two folders are zero KB, and `UserData` is only 8KB. I do not have a `CoreSimulator` folder in `Developer`. I already deleted the DocSets, which were taking up an additional ~2.5GB on top of the 9.22 that Xcode is using.

Answer (score 23):

Perhaps a more elegant solution would to be use the command line tools instead of Xcode.

You could delete Xcode entirely (or skip the install).
Instead of downloading and installing Xcode - open the command line (terminal app works out of the box) and type gcc.

That will pop up a window where you can install the command line tools. Click install, click agree and the C compilers and libraries and debuggers will all download and install.

On 10.11 the command line tools take about 200 MB of disk space. The dmg to install the Xcode 9 version beta command line tools is less than that as well, so it’s a pretty slim set of tools if you want to preserve disk space and can use another IDE / editor and don’t need all the features Xcode provides.

Comment: Many programs actually need the full Xcode to run correctly.

Comment: Wow @TeaTree what sort of programs? That’s a pretty huge dependency to need installed, but if you are a developer, maybe that is why.

Comment: [Deadbeat](https://github.com/DeaDBeeF-Player/deadbeef/) for example but what really makes me think so is that whenever I run into a problem with gcc, what fixes it is to install the complete Xcode.

Comment: Aah @TeaTree that makes sense if you have to get the source code and make your own build of the application. Good example for sure.