# Can't update Xcode even with 19gb free space

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-appstore, storage

I have an available update for Xcode that is in the 7gb range, and when I try to update I get an alert saying there isn't enough disk space - I checked my space and I have 19gb available (of 120gb).

Is this correct, or some kind of error? It seems like I have more than enough space.

Update: I deleted some earlier device support files and I now have 24gb free space and I still don't have enough space for the update. I feel like something's amiss here, as the update is only 7gb - I'm not sure if I should keep deleting things to free up space - will it even make a difference?

Update 2: I restarted my computer with 24gb free space and when I clicked Update, the update seemed to go forth and download - however when the download completed, the button switched back to "Update". When I clicked on it again, I got the "not enough space" alert again - even though now I have 26.5gb free space. I restarted again and keep getting the same message. Truly don't know what's going on here! Here's a screenshot, as requested, of my storage window:

[image]

Update 3:

Screenshot after running `df -h` in terminal as per request:

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of your 'About the Mac -> Storage' so we can see how you're calculating free space?

Comment: @fsb I made another update which includes a screenshot of my storage window.

Comment: Can you please run `df -h` in Terminal and post a screenshot of the result.  Then, see [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/b5uecg/how_much_space_does_xcode_require_to_update/ejgyn0j/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) for some additional troubleshooting steps (multiple steps so I don't want to post them here unless they actually help the OP).

Comment: @fsb I've added the screenshot to my question. I'll check out that thread, thanks.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370809/85275

Answer (score 2):

You might be close, but I downloaded from the developer website and I had  freed ~22 GB.

Try freeing up some more, like cache or movies you have watched, or software you don't use.

- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)
- [Reduce size of the Xcode application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287307/reduce-size-of-the-xcode-application/287309#287309)
- [Gigabytes of disk space shown as hidden space in DaisyDisk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk)

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Just so I understand, if I were to free up, say 21gb and it works, would the 7gb update actually take up an additional 7ish gb, or does it just need that space to install, then Xcode will go back to its regular size?

Comment: Also, why does it need that much space to install if it says it's 7gb? That's 3x as much as it says.

Comment: But going by some obvious logic, yes updates should need a lot space too. Xcode will revert to original size. Maybe a lot to unpack.. I. just hope that update file gets deleted automatically. mine was a zip, I had to delete it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm confused - Xcode itself seems to be around 6.5gb, so the update is more than twice that size for some reason. I did a scan with DaisyDisk and I can free up an additional 3gb if I delete "Archives" within Xcode - can I safely delete that stuff or is it important?

Comment: I deleted some earlier device support files and I now have 24gb free space and I still don't have enough space for the update. I feel like something's amiss here, as the update is only 7gb - I'm not sure if I should keep deleting things to free up space - will it even make a difference?

Comment: According to DaisyDisk I still have 18gb of "Hidden Space" - I'm not sure if that's safe to delete. In that, there's 1.1gb of "Purgeable Space" which is described as "system caches"

Comment: @KingTim https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk all I can do is link questions for storage etc because I don't have a setup to test it.. you can try a restart... just to freshen things up.