# Mac swift process blocks system, high memory pressure

Tags: macos, xcode, memory, swift

Recently, since XCode 11 when I use it, builds and indexes grab a lot of memory.

Activity monitor shows a process (it seems like it does so when indexing or building files) called swift and my Mac soon starts to lag. This process gathers a lot of memory (sometimes it gathers up to 70 GB) from my computer and I have to kill the process every time in order to get back to normal and start using my Mac as before.

[image]

[image]

How do I stop this memory pressure from increasing this much when compiling ?

Answer (score 1):

To clean your build in Xcode (under Product menu) and deleting cache in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` (not the whole Developer folder, as it [has simulators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287307/reduce-size-of-the-xcode-application/287309?r=SearchResults#287309) etc. too) was my original suggestion.

Finding on Stack Overflow got me these:

- Restart your Mac.
- **After** making a copy of your project in a safe place, right click on the project file and select "Show Package Contents". Delete the .xcworkspace file and rebuild your project. Use the backup file if it persists.
- Bugs in Swift which can be triggered by

  - Declaring arrays in multiple lines
  - Programming errors.
  - Several concatenations in one line
  - > ...it was caused by a 20 item array literal. Had to switch to different syntax.

and so on..

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782721/xcode-swift-indexing-forever
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831559/xcode-stuck-on-indexing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494082/swift-xcode-index-freezing-or-slow

New ones:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874341/xcode-indexing-takes-ages-and-uses-gigabytes-of-memory says cocoapods.
- And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649756/xcode-uses-huge-ram-memory-90gb This and some under the search [Xcode swift memory](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Xcode%20swift%20memory) indicate that it might be a new bug.

Your best bet is to use search and sort feature on SO, see linked and suggested questions to find problems in your code. Might even want to use source control to move back to the part where it was not problematic. After you've exhausted your search and trials, edit the question, I'd put a bounty. If it is not helpful, ask mods to kindly migrate.

Comment: Hi! I did what you said here and I am still getting the same frustration: The swift process starts to run and occupy a lot of my memory. I could not find any issues in my code that may cause this. I read about the issues that I may find ( the links you provided ) but I was not able to 'reproduce' the issue that is causing my swift process to start. Maybe you can give me more details on how to trace the issues

Comment: I am not aware of the issues in Swift or Xcode for that matter, unfortunately. You should revisit the questions, their "Linked" ones in the sidebar and then edit in the question what you've tried. I think this would not be very old to be migrated to SO. Also, see latest edit.