# Cleaner for Xcode needs permission clean files

Tags: xcode

The app in the App Store called "Cleaner for Xcode" displays the following warning message after trying to "clean". I understand it has to do with permissions, but not sure how to fix it. I'm also not sure how to get any support for this app nor contact the developer.

The error is:
"Need ~/Library/Developer permission to analyze and clean Xcode files"

I assume this means I need to give the app permissions to edit the Developer folder, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I've found the app in Github and posting this question directly to the developer: https://github.com/waylybaye/XcodeCleaner-SwiftUI

Comment: Try dragging a given folder to its Dock icon. That's one way to grant Sandbox access.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a separate app for cleaning Xcode files. I frequently do it manually, when the build logs are old, irrelevant. You can navigate to that `~/Library/Developer` folder and remove what you don't like. Be careful not to remove UserData or you'll lose your preferences. I remove simulators because I don't need them.

- [Reduce size of the Xcode application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287307/reduce-size-of-the-xcode-application/287309#287309)

I also set the iOS DeviceSupport folder as locked after cleaning it up, since it eats 2.5 GB for nothing.

- [How to stop Xcode downloading iOS support package of my iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380024/how-to-stop-xcode-downloading-ios-support-package-of-my-iphone/380032#380032)

Answer (score 0):

When an app needs that kind of permission, it needs to provide you with a way to give that permission. Usually that means it shows you a file-open window, displaying the directory it needs permission for. You can allow or deny access at that point.

If an app needs this permission and doesn't provide a way to actually give it the permission, the app is buggy and you should contact the developer for help.

Comment: I agree, but I can’t find a way to contact the developer

Comment: Maybe try Dev Cleaner for Xcode then. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?mt=12